# boost library..........pre-built variants?

Tags: c++, windows, boost

im just installing the boost library using an installer.

Its asking me which variants (about 8 options, 6 multithreaded and 2 single threaded) do i want to install. Im only installing this to get to grips and have a practice with boost, so im unsure?

Also, how do i use the libraries from VS02010 once ive 'installed' them using the installer?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) is your friend.  A read of the information on getting started on Windows would save you much time.

Most of the libraries are [header-only](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries%5d).  You can use these just by including the correct headers as described in the individual library docs.  If you want to use any of the ones that are not, you are going to need either to [build your own libraries, or install the ones that come prebuilt](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary).  This is what your question pertains to.  So you really must answer your own question - what is your target platform, and do you have to support multi-threaded programming?  if in doubt, install them all and use the ones you need on a case-by-case basis.

To use the Boost libs once you have installed or built them, just [include the relevant library in your project Linker options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library) as for any other static library.